# How to use different Babel transpilation options for different targets in the same process?

Tags: babeljs

I want to transpile two different things:

1. Node.js files using the babel require hook. (E.g. don't bother transpiling generators, arrow functions (etc) since this is Node 4.x.)
2. Code that will run in the browser using some bundling tool like babelify, which will be called from the above node.js files.

How is that possible with Babel 6 since it configures itself off a single `.babelrc` file? Especially since some of the same files will be used in both places, so I can't rely on different `.babelrc` files in different dirs.